# Why does Bootstrap only have classes for up to 12 columns? Why not more?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why am I limited to 12 columns? Why isn't by default more, for more flexibility?

Let me explain what confuses me. Let's say I want to create a simple page with a left menu, and a content on the right.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">Left menu</div> <!-- 258px -->
<div class="col-sm-9">Content</div> <!-- 772px -->

<div class="col-sm-4">Left menu</div> <!-- 343px -->
<div class="col-sm-8">Content</div> <!-- 687px -->
```

As seen in this example above, the difference between sm-3 and sm-4 is almost 100px for the menu! If I want the menu to be 300px, I can't use the grid. If I had more columns, I could be more precise than that.

Am I using the grid system the wrong way? Why is the grid divided into so few columns?

Comment: [Read this.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less)
You can set any number of columns.

Comment: Remember with Bootstrap you can also nest columns which may give you more flexibility.

Answer (score 11):

You can edit the amount of columns with LESS.

12 is the default because it is the most flexible grid pattern over any possible numbers up to 12.

```
 COLUMNS   | EVEN COLUMNS POSSIBLE
 1 column  = 1 (1x1)
 2 columns = 2 (1x2, 2x1)
 3 columns = 2 (1x3, 3x1)
 4 columns = 2 (1x4, 2x2, 4x1)
 5 columns = 2 (1x5, 5x1)
 6 columns = 4 (1x6, 2x3, 3x2, 6x1)
 7 columns = 2 (1x7, 7x1)
 8 columns = 4 (1x8, 2x4, 4x2, 8x1)
 9 columns = 3 (1x9, 3x3 9x1)
10 columns = 4 (1x10, 2x5, 5x2, 10x1)
11 columns = 2 (1x11, 11x1)
```

**`12 columns = 6 (1x12, 2x6, 3x4, 4x3, 6x2, 12x1)`**

Comment: The question is "why isn't the default more?", not "why isn't the default less?". So even though it's a nice argument to why 12 and not 8, it doesn't really answer why you'd stop at 12 instead of 24 or 100.

Comment: I think this answers the question - 12 is such a nice number for quick calculations, while providing good number of combinations. If you try to use bigger number, let's say 14 or 16  as a base for columns, you will quickly realize that it can't be divided as easily as 12.

Comment: "Why isn't the default more?" The answer goes back to the 12 column grid - because with 12 grids you have the most bang for your buck.

Lets say you have a 13 column grid. 
13 = 2 (1x13, 13x1)
14 = 4 (1x14, 2x7, 7x2, 14x1)
15 = 4 (1x15, 3x5, 5x3, 15x1)
and so on..  your best option is still going to be 12 - I'm not mathmatician, but I'm guessing any multiple of 12 is going to give you the largest combinations, but you typically don't need that many columns on a page.

You always have the option to create custom grids, but for the majority, 12 is going to be the most usable grid amount.

Answer (score 5):

Most versions of Bootstrap only use 12 columns to account for the following:

- Easier layout creation
- Responsive layout for mobile devices
- Proportional "blocks" to keep everything symmetrical
- Simpler "User Friendly" theme

You are correct. You are limited to a maximum width, and the width of your columns must add up to the maximum width and cannot exceed it. However, you are not forced to keep that policy on your website.

**You can always override the CSS and customize the column width to any way you want!**

To do this (and honor the maximum width of your website), you first need to find the number of pixels for the largest column, which is col-12. You can see that the maximum possible width is 1030px for your website.

Let's look at what you wanted:

> If I want the menu to be 300px, I can't use the grid.

You can actually do that while still using the grid to a certain extent. We just need to set the menu to be 300px (like you asked) and give the rest of the space (1030px - 300px = 730px) for the main content.

So we need a box for 300px and a box for 730px.

Here's what you can use:

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="width:300px;">Left menu</div> <!-- 300px -->
<div class="col-sm-9" style="width:730px;">Content</div> <!-- 730px -->
```

Basically, you can change your layout proportions to anything you want. The total width just needs match the rest of the website. I hope that helps.

-Dominick

Comment: If I add a style attribute like you suggested style="width:300px;", then on small screen (col-xs), the width will still be 300px, but instead it should be the full width of the screen, because we specified col-sm. It's not that easy, right? Secondly, Why is a 12-columns easier, and better for responsive than e.g. a 24 column layout? 24 can be divided by 2, 3, 4, 6, ... and I can be more close to the width I want, because I have more columns. Why by default 12?

Comment: If you want everything to be proportional (even on mobile) you can use percentages instead of specifying 300px. So I would say set it to 30% for the left-menu, and 70% for the main content.

Comment: Well, a 12-column layout was how Bootstrap developed their layout technique. It is more effective because the layout was only intended to grow as large as the body of the page and shrink as small as a few words. For anything smaller (such as designs) or bigger (such as backgrounds) it would be written in CSS or Javascript.

Comment: It's OK if the total columns in a row exceeds 12

Answer (score 1):

Well, The reason is very simple and that's because it can be divided by `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `6`, and `12`. Which is also very easy to count and get your layout done.

You can use the entire available space by using `col-12` to one `div` or `element`

or divide the same space into `two` equal `divs` by using the `col-6` class

or you can make `three` equal `divs` by using `col-4` class

or having `4 columns` by using `col-3` class

or even a `6 columns` by using `col-2` class

And even having a `12 columns` layout by using `col-1` class

Do you see? how easy it is to manipulate and calculate the space you desire.

Not to mention that there are other `grid` systems such as the `8` and `16` systems but each has its own advantages and disadvantages. But from my own perspective, I think the grid of `12`  columns is the most flexible since you can have `3` equal `divs`  which is a huge advantage in my opinion.

Answer (score -2):

As it would appear 12 is an arbitrary value, could it be 12 as there are 12" in a foot?

Comment: I accept this as an answer. (Though opinions may divide.) I recommend however to rephrase this without asking a (rhetoric) question. Because there are some (extremely lazy) readers, who get confused by a "?" in an answer.